# Optimise a function with numerous conditions that depends on the previous row in a Python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, simplify

I have the following dataframe:

| country_ID | ID | direction | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ESP_1 | 0 | IN | 2021-02-28 |
| ENG | 0 | IN | 2021-03-03 |
| ENG | 0 | OUT | 2021-03-04 |
| ESP_2 | 0 | IN | 2021-03-05 |
| FRA | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-07 |
| ENG | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-09 |
| ENG | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-10 |
| ENG | 2 | IN | 2021-03-13 |

I have implemented the following functionality:

```
ef create_columns_analysis(df):  
    df['visit_ESP'] = 0
    df['visit_ENG'] = 0
    df['visit_FRA'] = 0
    list_ids = []
    
    for i in range(len(df)):
        if df.loc[i,'country_ID'] == 'ENG':
            country_ID_ENG(df, i, list_ids)
        else:
          # case country_ID = {FRA, ESP_1, ESP_2}
          # other methods not specified

    return df
```

For each row with a specific country_ID, a similarly structured function is applied.

I would like to optimise or simplify the code of the country_ID_ENG function. The country_ID_ENG function is defined as follows:

```
def country_ID_ENG(df, i, list_ids):
    # If it is the first time the ID is detected
    if df.loc[i,'ID'] not in list_ids:
        # It adds up to one visit regardless of the direction of the ID
        df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
        # Add the ID to the read list
        list_ids.append(df.loc[i, 'ID'])
        # Assigns the error column a start message
        df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:1'
    # If it is not the first time it detects that ID
    else:
        # Saves the information of the previous row
        prev_row = df.loc[i-1]
        # If the current row direction is 'IN'
        if df.loc[i,'direction'] == 'IN':
            # Add a visit
            df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
            # Behaviour dependent on the previous row
            # If the current row direction is 'IN' and previous row is 'IN' 
            if prev_row['direction'] == 'IN':
                if prev_row['country_ID'] == 'FRA':
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:0'
                elif prev_row['country_ID'] in ['ESP_1','ESP_2']:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:2'
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
                else:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:3'   
            # If the current row direction is 'IN' and previous row is 'OUT' 
            else:
                if prev_row['country_ID'] == 'ENG':
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:0'
                elif prev_row['country_ID'] in ['FRA','ESP_2']:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:4'
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
                else:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:5'    
                    df.loc[i,'visit_ESP'] = 1
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
        # If the current row direction is 'OUT'
        else:
            # If the current row direction is 'OUT' and previous row is 'IN' 
            if prev_row['direction'] == 'IN':
                # If it detects an output before an input of the same 'country_ID', 
                # it calculates the visit time
                if prev_row['country_ID'] == 'ENG':
                    df.loc[i,'mean_time'] = df.loc[i,'date']-prev_row['date']
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:0'
                elif prev_row['country_ID'] in ['ESP_1','ESP_2']:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:6'
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
                    df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
                else:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:7'    
                    df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
            # If the current row direction is 'OUT' and previous row is 'OUT' 
            else:
                df.loc[i,'visit_ENG'] = 1
                if prev_row['country_ID'] == 'ENG':
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:8'
                elif prev_row['country_ID'] in ['FRA','ESP_2']:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:9'
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
                else:
                    df.loc[i,'error'] = 'ERROR:10'  
                    df.loc[i,'visit_ESP'] = 1
                    df.loc[i,'visit_FRA'] = 1
```

The above function uses the information from the current row and the previous row (if any) to create new columns for visit_ENG, visit_ESP, visit_FRA, mean_time and error.

For the example dataframe the function, applying the function country_ID_ENG to rows whose country_ID is equal to ENG, should return the following result:

| country_ID | ID | direction | date | visit_ENG | visit_FRA | visit_ESP | mean_time | error |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ESP_1 | 0 | IN | 2021-02-28 | - | - | - | - | - |
| ENG | 0 | IN | 2021-03-03 | 0 | 1 | 0 | NaN | ERROR:2 |
| ENG | 0 | OUT | 2021-03-04 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 days | ERROR:0 |
| ESP_2 | 0 | IN | 2021-03-05 | - | - | - | - | - |
| FRA | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-07 | - | - | - | - | - |
| ENG | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-09 | 1 | 1 | 0 | NaN | ERROR:9 |
| ENG | 1 | OUT | 2021-03-10 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NaN | ERROR:8 |
| ENG | 2 | IN | 2021-03-13 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NaN | ERROR:1 |

The function is very long, and the other functions for rows with country_ID equal to ESP or FRA will have the same complexity. I would like you to help me to simplify or optimise the code of this function to also take it into account when defining the country_ID_ESP and country_ID_FRA functions. I appreciate your help.

Comment: If the code works and you're looking for advice on improving it, [codereview.se] is the appropriate place. But see https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users first.

Comment: @Barmar ok, thanks!

Comment: could you provide you `dataframe` as a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had to accomplish something similar. My solution was to create a custom class to iterate over moving the some of the logic out of the loop and into the class. Its not a complete solution but enough to work with.

### main.py

```py
import pandas as pd
DATA= {
    'country_id': ['ESP_1', 'FRA', 'ENG', 'FRA'],
    'ID': [0, 1, 2, 0, ],
    'direction': ['IN', 'IN', 'OUT', 'OUT'],
    'date': ['2021-02-28', '2021-02-28', '2021-02-28', '2021-02-28']
}


class CountryIDs:
    def __init__(self, df: pd.DataFrame):
        self._list_ids = []
        self._country_ids = []
        self._df = df

    def __iter__(self):
        for tup in self._df.itertuples():
            yield tup, self._list_ids

    def update_list_ids(self, new_value):
        self._list_ids = [*self._list_ids, new_value.ID]
        self._country_ids = [*self._country_ids, new_value.country_id]

    def get_list(self):
        return [self._list_ids, self._country_ids]


def start():
    country_data = CountryIDs(pd.DataFrame(DATA))

    for named_tuple, list_ids in country_data:
        if named_tuple.ID not in list_ids:
            country_data.update_list_ids(named_tuple)

    print(ids.get_list())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start()
```

### result

```
[[0, 1, 2], ['ESP_1', 'FRA', 'ENG']]
```